# dyn.load("KNN_ANN.so") turn errors Symbol not found, Expected in: flat namespace when calling C function

Tags: c++, r, knn

I am a very beginner of writing C code. However, this is extract from the FNN library for testing purpose.

Here is my KNN_ANN.cpp code:

```
#include <ANN.h> // ANN header
#include <R.h>       // R header

    using namespace std;



void Rvector2ANNarray(ANNpointArray data_pts,
                            double *data,
                            const int n, const int d)
      {
    //copy data point address into n x d matrix from d x n R vector column by column 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      data_pts[i] = data+i*d;
    }               
  } 


extern "C" {


  void get_KNNX_kd(double *data, double* query,
                   int *k, int *dim,
                   int *n_pts, int *m_pts,
                   int *nn_idx, double *nn_dist)
  {
    const int               d=*dim;     // Actual Dimension
    const int               n=*n_pts;   // Number of Base Data points
    const int               m=*m_pts;   // Number of Query Data points
    const int               K = *k;     // Max. num of NN   
    const double        error_bound = 0.0;

    ANNidxArray     index = new ANNidx[K];      // Near neighbor indices
    ANNdistArray    dist = new ANNdist[K];      // Near neighbor squared distance       
    ANNpointArray   data_pts  = new ANNpoint[n];
    ANNpointArray   query_pts  = new ANNpoint[m];

    //copy data into  matrix from a vector column by column
    Rvector2ANNarray(data_pts, data, n, d);
    Rvector2ANNarray(query_pts, query, m, d);

    ANNkd_tree  *kd_tree    = new ANNkd_tree(data_pts, n, d);   

    register int ptr = 0;   
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)  // read query points
    {
      kd_tree->annkSearch(  // search
                           query_pts[i],        // query point
                           K,               // number of near neighbors
                           index,               // nearest neighbors index
                           dist,                // squared distance
                           error_bound);        // error bound

      for (int j = 0; j < K; j++)      //return result row by row
      {
        nn_dist[ptr] = sqrt(dist[j]);   // unsquare distance
        nn_idx[ptr]  = index[j] + 1;    // put indexes in returned array
        ptr++;
      } // end inner for
    } // end for

    delete[] index;
    delete[] dist;  
    //  delete kd_tree;

    //  annDeallocPts(data_pts);
    //  annDeallocPts(query_pts);
    delete[] data_pts;
    delete[] query_pts;
    delete kd_tree;

    annClose();

  }//end get_KNNX_kd



}//end extern
```

I have putted the ANN.h and R.h in the correct directory:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/include

Then I compiled the CPP code to generate the KNN_ANN.o and KNN_ANN.so in terminal using the following command:
R CMD SHLIB KNN_ANN.cpp

and when I go back to R and call the

```
dyn.load("KNN_ANN.so")
```

i got the following error message:

> ```
> Error in dyn.load("KNN_ANN.so") :    unable to load shared object '/Users/ypeng/KNN_ANN.so':   dlopen(/Users/ypeng/KNN_ANN.so, 6):
> ```
>
> Symbol not found: __Z8annClosev   Referenced from:
>   /Users/ypeng/KNN_ANN.so   Expected in: flat namespace  in
>   /Users/ypeng/KNN_ANN.so

Anyone please let me know if my CPP code has any issue..?

edit:
here is the code i mentioned for KNN search based on the kmeans cluster..

```
Cluster_Scoring <- function(score_table, newdata){ centers <- score_table n_centers <- nrow(centers) #for() #n_1=1:(nrow(newdata)/100) dist_mat <- as.matrix(dist(rbind(centers, newdata[n_1,]))) dist_mat <- dist_mat[-seq(n_centers), seq(n_centers)] a=max.col(-dist_mat) }
```

again, this code only works for small dataset and it returns error when running on the large dataset like mine (150Million rows/200 columns)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The FNN package contains quite a bit of source code. Among these is probably also a definition for the `annClose` function, that you linker is missing. Without knowing what you are trying to do, it is not possible to help you.

Comment: I am trying to use the same methodology on get.knnx to score a new data set based on the kmean cluster center file I generated from kmean(). The challenge I am facing here is I can only use base package in R. I understand the scoring the dataset is easy. However, I am dealing with a large dataset (200Million/ 100Column) , if I am not calling C/C++, I will went into a memory issue.

Comment: Why can you use only the base package in R? Why do you think going to C/C++ will help with your memory issues?

Comment: This function can be replaced the entire C/C++ algorithm:  Cluster_Scoring <- function(score_table, newdata){
  centers <- score_table
  n_centers <- nrow(centers)
  
  #for()
  #n_1=1:(nrow(newdata)/100)
  dist_mat <- as.matrix(dist(rbind(centers, newdata[n_1,])))
  dist_mat <- dist_mat[-seq(n_centers), seq(n_centers)]
  a=max.col(-dist_mat)
} .          however, i ran into this issue:“Error: cannot allocate vector of size 10Gb”

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include this code? It is really difficult to read like this. Also, why can't you use the existing FNN package?